# I was wondering what is the purpose of styles.scss magento 1.9.1 rwd theme

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, css, rwd-theme, scss

So for days, I have been trying to find an answer to what really is the purpose of styles.scss it only contains the code below.

"$mq-support: true;
$mq-fixed-value: false;

@import "framework";
@import "core";"

I have found that editing styles.scss and adding my changes to things like the header can act in some ways like a local xml for rendering in changes to the css, I mean in as far as it seems to compile to the css the same just without having to seek out the scss in the layout template for header and such. I found a few tutorials stating you never want to edit the scss located in the layout folder. So the end question is it better to edit the layout files from styles.scss or go directly into the layout folders and edit things such as header. What would be the best practice on editing these files? /* thanks in advance */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`styles.scss` is the main Compass/SASS file. You'll notice that almost all of the other `scss` files have an underscore at the beginning. That's because those are all included at some point. Files without an underscore however are the "main" files and get turned into normal CSS files after compilation. (This is why you'll find `style.css` but not `core/_common.css`)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. So if I am understanding correctly it would be a safe bet to edit the style.scss & that would be industry standard? (forgive me I am new to Magneto and just trying to make sure I am doing everything right)

Comment: This is more of a Compass/SASS thing than a Magento thing. You might even try reposting your question elsewhere. But I would say that you should stick to editing the files that start with underscores, and only edit the main files to manage includes.

Comment: Gotcha, off to look at tuts, on sass and compass. Thanks for taking the time to have a look at this and reply.